# How can i repeat the condition if the user wants to input many student name in the list and how can i list all of them. after i input "N"

Tags: c#

I only got the example of the program but how can i repeat the condition in order to get the desired output of the program. I'm confused on how I'm going to repeat the condition to add number in the "INSERT STUDENT {0}" what if  the users want to insert more than 10 student name.

here's is what i have started:

```
List<string> studentName = new List<string>();

        string insertStudentOne = "INSERT STUDENT 1:";
        string insertStudentTwo = "INSERT STUDENT 2:";
        string listOfStudent = "List of Student:";

        string studentOne;
        string studentTwo;

        Console.Write(insertStudentOne);
        studentOne = Console.ReadLine();
        studentName.Add(studentOne);

        Console.Write(insertStudentTwo);
        studentTwo = Console.ReadLine();
        studentName.Add(studentTwo);

        string selectAnswer = "DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?: ";
        string answerStr;
        Console.Write(selectAnswer);
        answerStr = Console.ReadLine();
        string name;

        if (answerStr.Equals("Y"))
        {
            {
                int addedStudent = 2;
                int sum;
                sum = addedStudent + 1;
                Console.Write("INSERTE STUDENT {0}: ", sum);
                name = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.Write("DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT(Y / N) ?: ");
             string addedStudent1= Console.ReadLine();
            studentName.Add(addedStudent1);

            if (addedStudent1.Equals("N"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(listOfStudent);
                Console.WriteLine(studentOne);
                Console.WriteLine(studentTwo);
                Console.WriteLine(name);

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

The sample program output should be like this:

### INSERT STUDENT 1: JAMES
INSERT STUDENT 2: JOHN
DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?:Y
INSERT STUDENT 3: MICHAEL
DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?:N
LIST OF STUDENTS:
JAMES
JOHN
MICHAEL

### INSERT STUDENT 1: JAMES
INSERT STUDENT 2: JOHN
DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?:N
LIST OF STUDENTS:
JAMES
JOHN

INSERT STUDENT 1: JAMES
INSERT STUDENT 2: JOHN
DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?:Y
INSERT STUDENT 3: MICHAEL
DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?:Y
INSERT STUDENT 4: WILLIAM
DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?:Y
INSERT STUDENT 5: JORDAN
DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?:N
LIST OF STUDENTS:
JAMES
JOHN
MICHAEL
WILLIAM
JORDAN

As you can see  the "INSERT STUDENT {0} "added +1 after the "INSERT STUDENT 2" and everytime the answer is "Y" but if i Input the Letter "N" it will display all the inserted name Like sample program#2 if Input "N" after Student 2 it will display the student quickly and will always ask me if i want to cointinue adding student.However, if i alsways insert "Y" it will not stop to print the student  inifinitely until i inserted "N". Some of my friends suggest that use foreach or LINQ to answer this. I'm just beginner in programming i want to learn programming deeper even i did not finish my college. i hope someone knows how to address my question. thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at loops. Here a while-loop is the obvious option.

Comment: The loop condition should be the answer to your "want to continue?" question. And in the loop count the number of rounds you have made in the loop and use that as the number for your student.

Comment: Your code above does not look complete. Does it compile?

Comment: yes it is compile.. i only did what i can but i think that's all i can do because i just started studying programming cause i really find it interesting but now i don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check out arrays or lists which can store many variables. Otherwise you may need to create hundreds of student variables.

You may use a do-while loop to achieve the problem.

```
string answerStr = "";
do {
    string selectAnswer = "DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?: ";
    Console.Write(selectAnswer);
    answerStr = Console.ReadLine();
    // get the user input
    // add the new user to a list or an array
    // then repeat the steps until the user gives an input other then "Y".
} while(answerStr == "Y");
```